# Django embed youtube video without having to use safe filter

Tags: python, html, django

I am writing a django site in which i would like to embed youtube videos within my posts. The only problem is, by default django sanitizes my posts and outputs the embed code as is. I can use the `|safe` filter to get round this, but then it allows any code to be injected and displayed. Does anybody know how i can mix text and embed urls without using the safe filter, and still have the youtube video output?

Comment: There are lots of ways to achieve what you're trying to do. Which one is best for you would depend on your existing code. Could you post the relevant view and template code?